# Is there an alternative to CSS sprites?

Tags: html, css, sprite

**Is there an alternative to CSS sprites ?**

I was hoping there was a way to specify the file names

```
file1.ico, file2.ico
```

instead of using a server created file and using CSS X Y Coordinates.

Are there plans for this in HTML 5.

For example instead of specifying a file, something like:

```
<file_blob src='path_to_folder'><?file_blob>
```

and then the individual files would be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a goole search

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=HTML5+download+folder

You can see there is a way to do this but it is not full supported:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/using-the-html5-download-attribute.html#fbid=IoQjm5oV80g

You could basically use the example provided adding some JavaScript, but it is not fully supported.

It doesn't look like a stable solution yet.